# grid workspaces in Sierra

Tags: macos, spaces

Trying to have a grid of workspaces which I can instantaneously switch between using directional keyboard commands.

The built in workspace switching comes with an irremovable delay which can be reduced but not eliminated, and limits to 1-D movement.

Have been using TotalSpaces which was perfect up until Mavericks, its okay (now) on ElCapitan, but apparently having problems on Sierra.

[image: totalspaces]

There are reddit forums and questions around the internet asking how to do this. I am looking at writing something myself, does anyone have an alternative or anything working?

Comment: upgraded to Sierra, updated totalspaces, seems fine! Will leave question as a gathering place for alternatives, should it ever come to pass that it stops working